# scki-kit SLIC segmentation not processing entire image

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I am attempting to segment this image (original is of the shape (5000,5000, 4):
[image]

Using the SLIC algorithm like so:

`segments = slic(img, n_segments=100000, compactness=.1, start_label=1)`

However the output does not show segmentation being done for the entire image:
[image]

When I reduce the amount of segments, it processes the entire image:

`segments = slic(img, n_segments=10000, compactness=.1, start_label=1)`
[image]

Is there a simple explanation why I cannot use `n_segments=100000`?

Comment: I don't know how to display your `slic` results (How do you do it?), but when I use your `img` and your `slic` commands, `segments` seems to have he same X/Y dimensions as `img` regardless of the `n_segments` value.  Do you have the latest versions of the packages?  Perhaps try in a virtual environment?

Comment: @rickhg12hs this is a geotiff and I’m using qgis to display it and the segment results. Currently using a virtual environment with the latest version of scikit image. BTW The original image is 5000x5000 so results might differ using the one posted here

Comment: Maybe it uses 16-bit labelling. Try 65,000 segments and then 66,000 to see if 65,535 is the cutoff.

Comment: @MarkSetchell tried both 66k and 65k - both are completely segmented

Comment: I assume there are no error messages, right? What is the `shape` of `segments`? If you rotate `img` 180 degrees, any interesting `slic` surprises? If you rotate both `img` and `segments` after the `slic`, how does the display look? Is there another way to display your results?